Can I in eloquent request to use diferent methods on condition?
In laravel 10 app when I need to read notifications of a user I do:
    if ($onlyUnread) {
        return auth()->user()->unreadNotifications()->latest()->paginate($backendPerPage);
    } else {
        return auth()->user()->notifications()->latest()->paginate($backendPerPage);
    }

I wonder if there is a way to write it in 1 line, like :
return auth()->user()->( $onlyUnread ? unreadNotifications() : notifications() )->latest()->paginate($backendPerPage);

?

yes, you can do it in a single line by placing the ternary operator inside curly braces.
return auth()->user()->{ $onlyUnread ? 'unreadNotifications' : 'notifications' }()->latest()->paginate($backendPerPage);

